# Javascript "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" when checking a variable's length

Tags: javascript

I'm building a `node` scraper that uses `cheerio` to parse the `DOM`. This is more or a vanilla javascript question though. At one part of my scrape, I'm loading some content into a variable, then checking the variable's `length`, like so:

```
var theHref = $(obj.mainImg_select).attr('href');
if (theHref.length){
   // do stuff
} else {
  // do other stuff
}
```

This works just fine, until I came across a url for which `$(obj.mainImg_select).attr('href')` didn't exist. I assumed that my `theHref.length` check would account for this and skip through to the `else: do other stuff` statement, but instead I got:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

What am I doing wrong here and how can I fix this?

Comment: `theHref` is undefined and thus, you can not read any property of it - for example `length` . In case that wasn't clear - this is a bug in cheerio which says that its API is supposed to be identical to jQuery's in attr.

Comment: Update, this isn't a bug but was changed in cheerio, which now abides to the newer jQuery API which does return undefined.

Comment: make sure that you properly attached the event by selecting id or class name etc.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can check that `theHref` is defined by checking against *undefined*.

```
if (undefined !== theHref && theHref.length) {
    // `theHref` is not undefined and has truthy property _length_
    // do stuff
} else {
    // do other stuff
}
```

If you want to also protect yourself against falsey values like `null` then check `theHref` is truthy, which is a little shorter

```
if (theHref && theHref.length) {
    // `theHref` is truthy and has truthy property _length_
}
```

Answer (score 6):

### Why?

You asked *why* it happens, let's see:

The [official language specificaion](http://es5.github.io/#x8.7.1) dictates a call to the internal `[[GetValue]]` method. Your `.attr` returns undefined and you're trying to access its length.

> If Type(V) is not Reference, return V.

This is true, since undefined is not a reference (alongside null, number, string and boolean)

> Let base be the result of calling GetBase(V).

This gets the `undefined` part of `myVar.length` .

> If IsUnresolvableReference(V), throw a ReferenceError exception.

This is not true, since it is resolvable and it resolves to undefined.

> If IsPropertyReference(V), then

This happens since it's a property reference with the `.` syntax.

Now it tries to convert `undefined` to a function [which results in a TypeError](http://es5.github.io/#x9.9).

Answer (score 4):

There's a difference between an empty string `""` and an undefined variable. You should be checking whether or not theHref contains a defined string, rather than its lenght:

```
if(theHref){
   // ---
}
```

If you still want to check for the length, then do this:

```
if(theHref && theHref.length){
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to others' proposals, there is another option to handle that issue.

If your application should behave the same in case of lack of "`href`" attribute, as in case of it being empty, just replace this:

```
var theHref = $(obj.mainImg_select).attr('href');
```

with this:

```
var theHref = $(obj.mainImg_select).attr('href') || '';
```

which will treat empty string (`''`) as the default, if the attribute has not been found.

But it really depends, on how you want to handle undefined "`href`" attribute. This answer assumes you will want to handle it as if it was empty string.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't doing some kind of numeric comparison of the length property, it's better not to use it in the if statement, just do:

```
if(theHref){
   // do stuff
}else{
  // do other stuff
}
```

An empty (or undefined, as it is in this case) string will evaluate to false (just like a length of zero would.)

Comment: Empty and undefined mean two fundamentally different things. For example, a cheerio selector like in OP's case (or a jQuery one on the web) can have length 0 and still not evaluate to false.

Comment: OP is evaluating a string, however. As of jQuery 1.6, all .attr() calls always return either a string or undefined.

Answer (score 1):

As has been discussed elsewhere, the `.length` property reference is failing because `theHref` is undefined. However, be aware of any solution which involves comparing `theHref` to `undefined`, which is not a keyword in JavaScript and can be redefined.

For a full discussion of checking for undefined variables, see [Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property-in-javascript) and the first answer in particular.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check whether the element length is undefined or not just by using

```
var theHref = $(obj.mainImg_select).attr('href');
if (theHref){
   //get the length here if the element is not undefined
   elementLength = theHref.length
   // do stuff
} else {
   // do other stuff
}
```